# Pass a variable from JS to PHP for MYSQL query without ajax

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I need to pass a JS variable to PHP that can be used in a MYSQL query

i tried with

`$varPQR = "<script> document.writeln(IdLocalStorage); </script>";  echo $varPQR;`

`$queryGetPqr = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}sfcwp_pqrs WHERE codigo_queja = {$varPQR}";`

didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use [form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and [hidden input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp) to pass data from client to server